# MySQL. Select without 1 day

Tags: mysql

Base: name, rate, dt.
Every day cost is inserted, I need to know the maximum cost without the first day. The first day of all products is different.

With all dates

```
SELECT `name`, MAX(rate) AS max
FROM `base`
GROUP BY `name`
```

This is similar to what I want, but not working.

```
SELECT `name`, MAX(rate) AS max, MIN(dt) AS min_dt
FROM `base`
WHERE `dt` > `min_dt`
GROUP BY `name`
```

Eample base

```
skirt, 6, 2018-10-10 00:00:00 
skirt, 7, 2018-10-11 00:00:00 
cap, 7, 2018-10-11 00:00:00 
skirt, 8, 2018-10-12 00:00:00 
cap, 6, 2018-10-12 00:00:00
```

Need

```
skirt, 8
cap, 6
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data and expected results?

Comment: SQL tables/resultsset are **orderless** by definition so `first` in SQL terms does not exists.. We need table structures (`SHOW CREATE TABLE base`), example data and expected results to give you answers, without we can only make educated guesses.  See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Paolo, of course

Comment: There's no date in your result.

Comment: @Strawberry, I need `name` and `rate`

Comment: @RaymondNijland There is a date in the database

Comment: So why is date in the select !?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use an inline view to get the min_dt for each name. Then we can join and exclude the minimum date rows

Something like this:

```
SELECT b.name
     , MAX(b.rate) AS `max`
  FROM ( SELECT d.name 
              , MIN(d.dt) AS min_dt
           FROM `base` d
          GROUP
             BY d.name
       ) m
  JOIN `base` b
    ON b.dt   > m.min_dt
   AND b.name = m.name 
 GROUP
    BY b.name
```

There are other query patterns that will achieve an equivalent result. My preference would to avoid a correlated subquery, but something like this would also return the specified result:

```
SELECT b.name
     , MAX(b.rate) AS `max`
  FROM `base` b
 WHERE b.dt > ( SELECT MIN(d.dt) 
                  FROM `base` d
                 WHERE d.name = b.name 
              )
 GROUP
    BY b.name
```

(With both of these query forms, if there is only row in `base` for a given `name`, the query will not return a row for that `name`.)

Comment: base does not respond. Explain for #1: 

id  


select_type  


table  


type  


possible_keys  


key  


key_len  


ref  


rows  


Extra  
 


1 

PRIMARY 

<derived2> 

ALL 

NULL 

NULL 

NULL 

NULL 

54 

Using temporary; Using filesort 


1 

PRIMARY 

b 

ALL 

NULL 

NULL 

NULL 

NULL 

68275 

Using where; Using join buffer 


2 

DERIVED 

d 

ALL 

NULL 

NULL 

NULL 

NULL 

68275 

Using temporary; Using filesort

Comment: Explain for #2: 1 

PRIMARY 

b 

ALL 

NULL 

NULL 

NULL 

NULL 

68010 

Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort 


2 

DEPENDENT SUBQUERY 

d 

ALL 

NULL 

NULL 

NULL 

NULL 

68010 

Using where

Comment: @YarNik,,,  yes, good catch. the join predicate should include matches on name.

Comment: second example too

Answer (score 0):

You should try to exclude the min dt using subqueries:

```
SELECT name, MAX(rate) AS max
FROM (SELECT name, rate, dt
      FROM   base B
      WHERE dt NOT IN (SELECT MIN(dt) FROM base WHERE name=B.name ))  as A 
GROUP BY name
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9e204a/10)

Comment: @YarNik now it is working and gives your expected result, you can check in the SQL fiddle